# openssl_pkcs7_verify(): signature OK, but cannot open for writing

Tags: php, openssl

I'm trying to decrypt a payload from a request it's working to decrypt but give me this error
[image]

I searched a lot but can't find nothing specific.

I also used this **print_r(openssl_error_string());** to see what errors are coming and on refresh give me on of these

error:0B084002:x509 certificate routines:X509_load_cert_crl_file:system lib

error:21075075:PKCS7 routines:PKCS7_verify:certificate verify error

error:2006D080:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:no such file

error:0D0D40D1:asn1 encoding routines:SMIME_read_ASN1:no content type

```
    $is_verified = openssl_pkcs7_verify(
    $tmp_smime_message_file->path,
    PKCS7_BINARY | PKCS7_NOCHAIN | PKCS7_NOINTERN,
    null,
    [__DIR__ . '/bundle.crt'],
    __DIR__ . '/test_public.crt',
    $tmp_decrypted_and_verified_message_file->path
);
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: Post the code that is generating the error.

Answer (score 1):

From **openssl_pkcs7_verify** doc-block:

> If the *outfilename* is specified, it should be a string holding
> the name of a file into which the certificates of the persons that
> signed the messages will be stored in PEM format.

So, you need indicate valid file path in **$signers_certificates_filename** instead of current **null** value